# Is this a definition in C?

Tags: c, declaration, definition

According to the C standard, this is considered a definition

```
int x;
```

Because it declares x and allocates storage. But is this also a definition?

```
int *x;
```

That is, does declaring a pointer variable or array variable allocate storage? I'm guessing no because we have to use malloc.

Comment: Replace the type (`int*`) with T, so .. `T x`: is this considered a definition?

Comment: In both cases, an object is allocated.  In the second case, that object happens to be a pointer.

Comment: You, like thousands before, need to learn to distinguish pointers from the stuff they point at. Storage for a pointer is storage too. A pointer is data in its own right, regardless of whether it is in turn used to access more data.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to use `malloc`. You can assign a null pointer value to `x`, or you can assign it the address of some object: `int n = 42; int *x; x = &n;`

Comment: The problem with declaring it as int* x is that you would misread int* x, y as int* x; int* y when it is actually int* x; int y.

Comment: `int x;` defines an object of type `int`. `int *x;` defines an object of type `int*`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`int* x;` is a definition. It allocates storage to store the pointer. It does not allocate any storage for an integer - that's why you need `malloc` if you don't want to point to an existing variable (or other memory location).

A pure declaration would be something like `extern int x;` or `extern int* x;`, which would then have a corresponding definition in a different compilation unit.

Answer (score 4):

`int *x;` allocates storage. Variable `x` is allocated storage equal to `sizeof(int *)`. It contains a garbage value if it's at block scope or a null pointer value if it's at file scope.

Comment: It initially contains garbage if it's at block scope. It initially contains a null pointer value if it's at file scope.